# Filtering twice with multiple variables and counting rows

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, count

I have this data frame that is grouped by id_station, id_parameter, "zona", and its date.

```
id_station id_parameter   zona    year   month  day  mediaDiaria sdDiaria Count
      
 1 AJM        CO           SO     2019     1     1       0.281   0.181     21
 2 AJM        CO           SO     2019     1     2       0.367   0.230     24
 3 AJM        CO           SO     2019     1     3       0.371   0.160     24
 4 AJM        CO           SO     2019     1     4       0.312   0.185     24
 5 AJM        CO           SO     2019     1     5       0.296   0.168     24
 6 AJM        CO           SO     2019     1     6       0.225   0.142     24
 7 AJM        CO           SO     2019     1     7       0.281   0.0873    21
 8 AJM        CO           SO     2019     1     8       0.388   0.236     24
 9 AJM        CO           SO     2019     1     9       0.421   0.265     24
10 AJM        CO           SO     2019     1    10       0.225   0.103     24
```

What I want to do is to filter March 1st, 2019 to February 29, 2020. I would treat this as "Year 1." Afterwards, I want to count the number of rows in Count, in Year 1 and per id_station, to eliminate all rows from stations that have less than 275 rows (days) with Count > 18.

I have tried the following with filter:

```
Year1in2019CO <- datosCO %>%
                 filter(year == 2019, month %in% c(3:12)) %>%
                 group_by(id_station, id_parameter, zona, year, month, day) %>%
                 summarise(mediaDiaria = mean(valor, na.rm = TRUE), sdDiaria = sd(valor, na.rm = TRUE), 
                 Count = sum(!is.na(valor)))
Year1in2020CO <- datosCO %>%
                 filter(year == 2020, month %in% c(1:2)) %>%
                 group_by(id_station, id_parameter, zona, year, month, day) %>%
                 summarise(mediaDiaria = mean(valor, na.rm = TRUE), sdDiaria = sd(valor, na.rm = TRUE),
                 Count = sum(!is.na(valor)))

Year1CO <- bind_rows(Year1in2019CO, Year1in2020CO)
```

It does the job. But is there a way to do this while only creating one data frame, instead of 3?

And I have tried the following for the counting rows part:

```
YEAR1dfCO_2 <- Year1CO %>% 
           group_by(id_station) %>%
           summarise(dws = sum(Count > 18))
```

And while it does give me what I need, I do not know how to eliminate all data from stations with less than 275 rows in Count (being > 18) in Year 1 from the original dataset (Year1CO).

Can you please help me?

Comment: First to simplify matters, I would create a new column combining the year, month and day into a proper Date object.  That would make filtering much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work. First, filter year 1 rows using a constructed date then remove the stations based on the condition you described.

```
library(tidyverse)
yr1 <- datosCO %>%
  mutate(d = as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep = "-"))) %>%
  filter(between(d, as.Date("2019-03-01"), as.Date("2020-02-29"))) %>%
  group_by(id_station, id_parameter, zona, d) %>%
  summarise(mediaDiaria = mean(valor, na.rm = TRUE),
            sdDiaria = sd(valor, na.rm = TRUE), 
            Count = sum(!is.na(valor)))

yr1 %>%
  group_by(id_station) %>%
  filter(sum(Count > 18) < 275) %>%
  ungroup()
```